# iOS debugBlock macro

Tags: c++, objective-c, c, ios, macros

I'm sure alot of you are aware of the macro

```
#ifdef DEBUG 
#define DebugLog( s, ... ) NSLog( @"<%p %@:(%d)> %@", self, [[NSString stringWithUTF8String:__FILE__] lastPathComponent], __LINE__, [NSString stringWithFormat:(s), ##__VA_ARGS__] )
#else
#define DebugLog( s, ... ) 
#endif
```

This of course creates a function called DebugLog which you use in place of NSLog. Then when you change your project out of debug it will stop executing all of the NSLogs statements.

What I was thinking is is there a way to get this to work but with blocks. In other words I want to be able to do this:

```
DebugBlock(^{
    //Code to only be executed while in Debug
});
```

Yes, I realize I can just do #ifdef DEBUG everywhere but that's not fancy enough for me :).

Comment: Ay, caramba, call me a curmudgeon, but "not fancy enough for me" as a reason to not use `#ifdef`??

Comment: Blocks are cleaner and have better readability IMO. It wasn't so much of trying to be 'fancy' I just added that in so people wouldn't try to use that as an answer. Since that in fact does not answer the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I feel kind of foolish about how simple it was but here is the solution.

```
#ifdef DEBUG 
#define DebugBlock( ... ) dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_LOW, 0), ##__VA_ARGS__)
#else
#define DebugBlock( ... ) 
#endif
```

The the usage looks a little something like this:

```
DebugBlock(^{
    int i = 12; 
    int b = 400; 
    int Answer = i+b; 
    NSLog(@"%d", Answer);
});
```

You can also change the dispatch type fo async if your heart desires.